# Only ONE CSS File for Visitors (and more for Admins)

Tags: theming, commerce

So I just started creating a theme for my first big drupal project, and instantly had to quietly cry in a corner, as I saw how many css files Commerce Kickstart 2 and Omega4 are serving by default.

**My plan** is to essentially reduce the number of CSS files served to only one, perhaps two (depending on the current page), for the minimum amount of http-requests, without having to manually exclude them all in the theme settings file (which would be an unreliable solution, as new CSS files may get added upon installment of a new module). In addition, exceptions will have to be handled depending on a user role; so visitors should really only get one or two css files, whereas admins shall be served with all CSS files, that are required for the control panel overlay, as well.

Thus **my question:** Is there a way for me to easily smack those fancy admin- and maintenance-related CSS files back in, only to be loaded for admins?

Basically I want regular visitors to only load my `global.css` file, whereas admins also get the CSS files of the basetheme as well as `commerce_kickstart_menus.css`. (For some reason, `toolbar_megamenu.css` already gets served to admins only.)

Any help or hints as how I could go about this would be super-appreciated!

Comment: Are you aware Drupal has context-aware CSS aggregation built right into core? For example, users without permissions to view the admin menu will be served aggregated files _without_ the admin menu styles, and so on.

Comment: Yeah, if this is your first time working with a Drupal site like this, turning on CSS aggregation in your performance settings is the way to experience this. What you're seeing isn't specific to Kickstart or Omega - it's a Drupal thing in general that you should only see in development.

Comment: thanks guys, but just turning on css aggregation is not precisely what I'm looking for here. in addition to only serve one (and for subpages, two) css file(s), I also want to get rid of all the other extermal css files that are being serves by various modules or the basetheme.

Comment: Related: https://drupal.org/node/264556

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this by extending a [hook_css_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_css_alter/7) in your template.php for module file.

```
function hook_css_alter(&$css) {
  global $user;  //  Use this object to check current user roles

  //  The $css variable is an array of all of the css files that will be loaded
}
```

Comment: hey Desmond!
thanks for your reply and for introducing me to hook_css_alter! <3
after some more _research_ on the $user and $css array, this is my current function:
`function HOOK_css_alter(&$css){
  global $user;
  if (!in_array('administrator', $user->roles)) {
    foreach($css as $key => $val){
      if (strpos($key,'HOOK') == false) { unset($css[$key]); }
    }
  }
}`
it appears to be working as intended, but since I'm still new to all of this, I would greatly appreciate any feedback, should you know a more efficient way. :3

edit: uh, inline-comments make code unreadable, sorry about that